# PHPExcel Fetch Database Fieldnames to Exported Excel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I got the following code which works fine, but it does not bring the database field names. How can I bring the field names, or even bring some title names at the first row?

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['target_id']); 
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['form_id']); 
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('f'.$rowCount, $row['update_date']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('g'.$rowCount, $row['user_id']);
            $rowCount++; 
             echo "<br>New record created successfully";
        }
```

Comment: Given that you're referencing the column names as `$row['target_id']);`, `$row['form_id']);`, etc.... you can use `$headers = array_keys($row);` for the first row that you fetch to get an array of the column names.... but specify "associative" when you fetch, else you'll get both associative and enumerated

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate SQL query to fetch your column headers and insert those separately, for example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM database.table WHERE column_name = column_name;';
```

And then insert the headers into your excel worksheet, something like:

```
    $res = mysqli_query($sql);
    $heads = mysqli_fetch($res);

    $headers = array();
    $loop = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $headers[$loop] = $row;
        $loop ++;
    }

    $r = 0;
    $c = 1;
    foreach ($headers as $k => $v) {
        if(isset($v['column_name']) && '' != $v['column_name']) {
            $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($c, $r, $v['column_name']);
        }
        $c++;
     }
```